# Class with many subclasses filled depend on field value

Tags: java, spring, database, data-structures

I have a problem with my data structure.

```
public class Disposition{
    private long Id;

    private DispositonType dispositonType;

    private DispositionDetailsA dispositionA;
    private DispositionDetailsB dispositionB;
...
}
```

There is table in database 'disposition' and there are many tables 'disposition_details_*'

And I have export to another data structure, and I need to transform this data to this new datastructure. Some part of fields are common for disposition_details_*, some are unique just for one dispositionType

Now I have big switch case for each of fields which are common in disposition_details_*, but it starts to be problematic, and I would like to refactor it, but I don't have idea what can I do?

I thouth about make interfaces, but I'm not sure if it will work propertly, because fields can have different names even if it has the same information. I can't separate common information to another tabele, because it is on production...

Could you sugest me any solution. Thank you in advance.

Best regards,
Patryk

//Edit

```
public class Disposition {
    private long Id;

    private DispositioType dispositionType;

    private DispositionDetailsA dispositionDetailsA;
    private DispositionDetailsB dispositionDetailsB;
    private DispositionDetailsC dispositionDetailsC;
    private DispositionDetailsD dispositionDetailsD;

    
}


public class DispositionDetailsA {
    private long Id;
    private Dispositon disposition;
    private String localBankAccount;
    private boolean isForeignBankAccount;
    private String foreignBankAccount;
    private String foreignBankSwift;

    private String departmentName;
}



public class DispositionDetailsB {
    private long Id;
    private Dispositon disposition;
    private String localBankAccount;
    private boolean isForeignBankAccount;
    private String foreignBankAccount;
    private String foreignBankSwift;

    private String customerName;
    private String documentNumber;
}



public class DispositionDetailsC {
    private long Id;
    private Dispositon disposition;
    private String localBankAccount;
    private boolean isForeignBankAccount;
    private String foreignBankAccount;
    private String foreignBankSwift;

    private boolean isExportable;

    private String documentNumber;
    private String documentTitle;
}

public class DispositionDetailsC {
    private long Id;
    private Dispositon disposition;

    private String departmentName;
    private String customerName;
    private String documentDescription;
}


@Getter
@Setter
public class ExportDataStructure{

    private long Id;
    private String localBankAccount;
    private boolean isForeignBankAccount;
    private String foreignBankAccount;
    private String foreignBankSwift;
    private String departmentName;
    private String customerName;
    private String documentNumber;
    private String documentTitle;
    private String documentDescription;
}

public class Exporter{

    public ExportDataStructure exportDisposition(Disposition disposition){
        ExportDataStructure export = new ExportDataStructure();
        export.setId(disposition.getId());
        export.setLocalBankAccount(this.exportLocalBankAccount(disposition));
        ...
    } 

    private String exportLocalBankAccount(Disposition disposition){
        switch(disposition.getDispositionType()){
            case DispositionA:
                return disposition.getDispostionDetailsA().getLocalBankAccount();
            case DispositionB:
                return disposition.getDispostionDetailsB().getLocalBankAccount();
            case DispositionC:
                if(disposition.getDispositionC().isExportable()){
                    return disposition.getDispostionDetailsC().getLocalBankAccount();
                }
                else return null;
            case DispositionD:
                return null;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could you provide a more complete example?

Comment: @Jeremy post edited

Comment: Side note: when you start making fields like `field1, field2, field3, ...` or `fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, ...`, it's a common code smell that you may really be looking for a collection instead of explicit fields.

Comment: @Rogue i have updated fileds name. It is just an example, because I can't show normal code.

Answer (score 0):

Use an interface that handles the necessary logic.

```
public interface DispositionInterface {
    String getExportableBankAccount()
}

class DispositionDetailsA implements DispositionInterface {

     @Override
     public String getExportableBankAccount() {
         return localBankAccount;
     }

}

class DispositionDetailsB implements DispositionInterface {

     @Override
     public String getExportableBankAccount() {
         return isExportable ? localBankAccount : null;
     }
}
```

Comment: I thought about it buy I will need 7/8 interfaces. Is it ok? And what about switch case? It will not eliminate problem with it.

Comment: Can the interfaces be combined? Also, you cannot avoid the switch case when choosing a disposition with the way you have them modeled. This only encapsulates the logic after choosing a disposition with a single method call. Another approach is that you can create a list of dispositions, all having a common interface.